# Arduino encrypted Radio communication

Tags: arduino-mega, wireless, rf

Is there any way or library to communicate two Arduino devices with encrypted connection using modules NRF24L01 or "433Mhz RF" ? Similar encryption like CCMP in Wi-Fi network.

Comment: There is no answer at all.

Comment: Ups, the question, if this answers your question was added automatically. Your original was closed because it needs more focus. You asked the exact question again, so this question will also be closed

Comment: Please read both questions, and you will see the difference...

Comment: I have done so. Both question are exactly the same. Besides exchanging one "wireless" with "Radio" in the title. The rest is exactly the same.

Comment: Please compare.

Comment: New Question: Is there any way or library to communicate two Arduino devices with encrypted connection using modules NRF24L01 or "433Mhz RF" ? Similar encryption like CCMP in Wi-Fi network.

Old Question(updated, but it's already closed):What is the best way/library to communicate two Arduino devices with encrypted connection using modules NRF24L01 or "433Mhz RF" ?

Comment: When I google "Arduino encryption library" I find [this](https://www.arduinolab.net/aes-encryptiondecryption-using-arduino-uno/) about an AES library for example. Would that help you?

Comment: Ah, ok, now I'm seeing. You already edited your old question to replace the "best way", that was critisized in the comments.

Comment: you asked a `yes/no` question that has an answer of `yes` ... that seems kind of pointless to me

Comment: ESP-NOW offers an encrypted mode at a lower performance rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communicating and Encryption are to completely separate things. How you communicate (with what device) has no relevance to encryption. True, there are devices that can themselves encrypt data, but they tend to be higher-end or geared towards a specific purpose (such as WiFi).

What you send is just data. What that data consists of is entirely up to you.  If you want your communications encrypted then send encrypted data before sending it and decrypt it after receiving it.

Of course, you have to then consider such things as sharing of keys, etc.

There are numerous ways of encrypting data, but one of the easiest to implement on Arduino is AES, for which there is a library [here](https://spaniakos.github.io/AES/index.html).